# Populate Elevation Data in GPX using FME

Tags: raster, point, fme-form, elevation, gpx

New to FME, and I have now spent more time than I would like to admit on this and need some pointers.

I have a GPX file that was made from a Shapefile. It has no elevation data.

I have the Terrain50 DEM as a GeoTIFF. I am using `PointsOnRasterValueExtractor` in FME to allocate the elevation data to the points before resaving the GPX. I have many thousands of these to do so I want to be able to batch process this.

I have checked that the two datasets are in the same projection, when I view the raster dataset in FME it has the data I need but I can't seem to populate the GPX Elev field. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How are you attempting to populate the Elev field? As per the documentation for the [**PointsOnRasterValueExtractor**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pointonrastervalueextractor.htm) transformer,

> The interpolated values are added to a new list attribute, named
> _band{}.value and _band{}.palette{}.value, respectively.

You will need to use an **[AttributeManager](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/attributemanager.htm?Highlight=attributemanager)** transformer to assign these values to the Elev field. Because, the PointsOnRasterValueExtractor transformer creates list attributes, you'll need to select the position of the list of your `_band{}.value`. Assuming your DEM is a single band, the list index should be `0`. Then, with a writer, write them to the GPX files.

Comment: Can I add a screenshot at all? My raster is returning the Band ) values and when I look at the feature information is has Band 0 (REAL32) with a value. But I still cannot get that Value to populate the ele tag in my GPX. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes you can edit your post and insert an image.

Comment: thank you - I've added a picture

Answer (score 0):

The doc for that writer says:

```
Feature Attribute   GPX XML Entity 
elevation           ele (The writer ignores this value, 
                    using the z-value of the geometry instead.)
```

So if you put a 3DForcer transformer in there, and set it to use the value of _band{0}.value then it should write that information out to the GPX file.